# Compareto with boolean is not working

Tags: java

My program is supposed to output the date today, the day before, the day tomorrow, and the day in the future. The ONLY problem is getting the before and compareTo part. My second class called DateAD is supposed to get yesterday's date. Compareto, however, doesn't work (it says it can't find symbol).

```
`DateAD dAD = new DateAD();
  System.out.println("The date is: " + dAD);

  if (dAD.getYesterday().compareTo(dAD) < 0) 
  {
  System.out.println("The day before is: " + dAD.getYesterday());
  } 
  else 
  {
 System.out.println("The day before is invalid");
 }`
```

I tried putting return (dAD.getYesterday().compareTo(dAD), but that didn't work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show us how you're defining `compareTo` in `DateAD`.

Comment: Or, more likely, _not_ defining `compareTo` ... (P.S. Is [this](http://pastebin.com/qsrW1viu) your code?  If so, please don't expect us to go hunting all over the Internet for your code when you ask a question here.)

Comment: Why are you comparing? Is like you don't trust yesterday function. If so write a unit test. Don't litter code with safety checks.

Comment: Okay. I thought that compareto will getyesterday from my other class and it will get it when it is less than 0. That's what I got out of it.

Comment: @ajb - no, I would never paste my code on pastebin.

Comment: @sw3etsauce must be one of your classmates, then ... :)

Comment: Probably! Good thing they didn't put their name on it o_o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison is just an unnecessary safety check that getyesterday returns date in past.

```
DateAD dAD = new DateAD();
System.out.println("The date is: " + dAD);
System.out.println("The day before is: " + dAD.getYesterday());
```

If DateAD is your class then you can write a unit test to ensure getYesterday works.

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense. I did that for the others but I guess I don't have to check if it is invalid since the user isn't inputting anything.

Comment: Yes, you can validate today if that is inputted by user, but getYesterday should only fail if they enter the earliest date available, but in that case I would hope getYesterday would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DateAD` class needs to implement `Comparable<DateAD>` and the method `compareTo`.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't _need_ to implement `Comparable` if it's not going to be used anywhere (like a `sort` method) that requires a `Comparable`.  If the only use of `compareTo` is to call it explicitly, then `Comparable` isn't needed.  But yeah, adding  `implements Comparable<DateAD>` seems like a good idea.